# Remove particular combinations from itertools.combinations

Tags: python

Suppose we have a pair of tuples where tuples can be of different length. Let's call them tuples `t1` and `t2`:

```
t1 = ('A', 'B', 'C')
t2 = ('d', 'e')
```

Now I compute all combinations of length 2 from both tuples using itertools:

```
import itertools
tuple(itertools.combinations(t1 + t2, 2))
```

Itertools generator produces all possible combinations, but I need only those which occurs between tuples; the expected output is

```
(('A', 'd'), ('A', 'e'), ('B', 'd'), ('B', 'e'), ('C', 'd'), ('C', 'e'))
```

I wonder what is best approach to remove undesired combination.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `itertools.product` :

```
>>> t1 = ('A', 'B', 'C')
>>> t2 = ('d', 'e')
>>> from itertools import product
>>> 
>>> list(product(t1,t2))
[('A', 'd'), ('A', 'e'), ('B', 'd'), ('B', 'e'), ('C', 'd'), ('C', 'e')]
```

If you are dealing with **short tuples** you can simply do this job with a list comprehension :

```
>>> [(i,j) for i in t1 for j in t2]
[('A', 'd'), ('A', 'e'), ('B', 'd'), ('B', 'e'), ('C', 'd'), ('C', 'e')]
```